# AFNetworking is not sending a request

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to learn AFNetworking by trying to create a simple commandline app. The network request is not being made at all. I used charles proxy to see if any requests are being made to the api server but none are being made. 
Any pointers?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {   
    NSString * BaseURLString = @"http://api.erail.in/pnr?key=599c6647e&pnr=673607";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSLog(@"Hi!");
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *status = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
        NSLog(@"HI!");
        NSLog(@"%@", status);

    }
                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Couldn't reciev the data");
                                     }
     ];
    [operation start];
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request runs asynchronously, and as a result the `main` function is ending, and thus the app is terminating, before the request is done.

You need to have an `NSRunLoop` running to keep the app alive and process AFNetworking's `NSURLConnection` events properly. The easiest way to do that is to not use a command line app, but instead use a standard Cocoa or Cocoa Touch app, and start the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` in the appropriate place. The `NSRunLoop` will keep running, the app won't immediately terminate, and AFNetworking's `NSURLConnection` will have a chance to process the request and await the response.

If you really want to do a command line app, then you can keep the run loop alive yourself:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        BOOL __block done = NO;
        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = ...
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // do your success stuff

            done = YES;
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            // do your failure stuff

            done = YES;
        }];
        [operation start];

        while (!done && [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]) {
            // this is intentionally blank
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. is there a way to this without the app terminating?

Comment: Add your own run loop. See code sample in revised answer.